# Need help retrieving largest index from array

Tags: java

I'm stuck... My code was working earlier, but now it just hangs. On top of that I can't seem to get my `getHighest` and `getSmallest` methods to return the correct values. I don't know if I'm just not catching something. Any help would be great!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Rainfall
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    final int MONTHS = 12;
    double[] rain = new double[MONTHS];
    initRain(rain);
    double total = totalRain(rain);
    double average = averageRain(rain, total);
    double most = mostRain(rain);
    double least = leastRain(rain);
    DecimalFormat digit = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
    System.out.println("The total rainfall of the year is " + digit.format(total));
    System.out.println("The average rainfall of the year is " + digit.format(average));
    System.out.println("The month with the highest amount of rain is " + most);
    System.out.println("The month with the lowest amount of rain is " + least);
  }
  public static void initRain(double[] array)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
    {  
      System.out.print("Enter Rainfall for month " + (x + 1) + ": ");
      array[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
  }
  public static double totalRain(double[] array)
  {
    double total = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
      total += array[x];
    return total;
  }
  public static double averageRain(double[] array, double total)
  {
    return total / array.length;
  }
  public static double mostRain(double[] array)
  {;
    double maximum = array[1];
    int value = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 12; i = i++)
    {
      if (array[i] >= maximum)
        maximum = array[i];
        value = i;
      }
    return value;
  }
  public static double leastRain(double[] array)
  {
    double minimum = array[0];
    int value;
    for (int i=0; i < 12; i++)
    {
      if (array[i] <= minimum) 
        minimum = array[i];
        value = i;
      }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: In the `leastRain()` and `mostRain()` methods you are returning value in the for loop, but you should actually return it after the loop...

Comment: Also, when iterating over arrays, it is pretty much never ever a good idea to hard code the length into a for loop... even if you dont think it will ever change.  Always use `array.length`, or at least a variable that you can quickly change later if the array length changes.  `for (int i=0; i < array.length ; i++)`

Comment: Ahhh thank you! that did help, can you explain why code is just hangin right now though :( I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You've also got an interesting i = i++ in the mostRain(...) for loop. That's your problem. You are setting i to the value of i before it is incremented. So in effect not incrementing i.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by hanging.  You mean it is running, but not producing any discernible result?  Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: Compiling everything perfectly! but when I actually try to run i.e. java Rainfall I get Enter rainfall for month 1 through 12 but then the underscore blinks at the next line expecting me to type something but I can't type anything

Comment: It's the  `i = i++` in the `mostRain(...)` for loop!

Comment: sorry to be annoying, but I just changed that, compiled it and ran and it is still hanging. there must be something sitting somewhere that I am not seeing...

Comment: The problem is that `i++` returns the value of `i` ***before the variable is incremented***, so the increment step of your loop is the same as writing `i=i`.  Thus, the variable `i` never reaches the escape condition of the loop.

Comment: Thank you all for the Help!! changing those miniscule errors did the trick! :)

Answer (score 3):

Your program hangs because of this line:

```
for (int i=0; i < 12; i = i++)
```

The problem is that `i++` returns the value of `i` ***before the variable is incremented***, so the increment step of your loop is the same as writing `i=i`.  Thus, the variable `i` never reaches the escape condition of the loop.

it should be:

```
for (int i=0; i < 12; i++)
```

Cleaned up your code a little bit, can be improved a lot. There were many simple errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Rainfall
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    final int MONTHS = 12;
    double[] rain = new double[MONTHS];
    initRain(rain);
    double total = totalRain(rain);
    double average = averageRain(rain, total);
    int most = mostRain(rain);
    int least = leastRain(rain);
    DecimalFormat digit = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
    System.out.println("The total rainfall of the year is " + digit.format(total));
    System.out.println("The average rainfall of the year is " + digit.format(average));
    System.out.println("The month with the highest amount of rain is " + (most + 1));
    System.out.println("The month with the lowest amount of rain is " + (least + 1));
  }
  public static void initRain(double[] array)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
    {
      System.out.print("Enter Rainfall for month " + (x + 1) + ": ");
      array[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
  }
  public static double totalRain(double[] array)
  {
    double total = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
      total += array[x];
    return total;
  }
  public static double averageRain(double[] array, double total)
  {
    return total / array.length;
  }
  public static int mostRain(double[] array)
  {
    double maximum = array[1];
    int value = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 12; i++) {
      if (array[i] >= maximum) {
        maximum = array[i];
        value = i;
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
  public static int leastRain(double[] array)
  {
    double minimum = array[0];
    int value = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 12; i++)
    {
      if (array[i] <= minimum) {
        minimum = array[i];
        value = i;
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```